# How to implement the same keyboard shortcut for multiple ViewController in AppKit/Cocoa?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit

Does anyone know how I would be able to add a local shortcut (backspace) to delete the selected row for my table view in my Split View controller?

Please note that I am using AppKit/Cocoa.

My app has a NSSplitViewController with 3 panes.  I would like to have the same shortcut of backspace to delete the selected cell for my sidebar tableview AND my main tableview (middle view).  When the delete button is pressed only one cell should be deleted from either the sidebar tableview or the main tableview, but not both.

I was thinking I might be able to achieve this by `addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching:handler:)` , however, there is not a way to know whether the delete should happen in the sidebar tableview OR the main tableview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSTableView and backspace event (delete row) - fieldeditor/firstresponder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946260/nstableview-and-backspace-event-delete-row-fieldeditor-firstresponder)

Comment: Or [NSTableView + Delete Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668847/nstableview-delete-key)

Comment: Or [Deleting entries from tableview with keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929756/deleting-entries-from-tableview-with-keypress)